# Keep widget on top in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, widget

I'm creating an application which has a "floating" widget which can be dragged around inside the application window. But it starts up, or tends to go behind other widgets sometimes. Is there any way to make sure that the widget in my application stays on top of all other widgets whenever it is made visible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the flag [`Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#WindowType-enum) for your QWidget. This will force your widget to stay on top of all other windows

Comment: The question is about a widget, but this flag is related to windows, and all the examples around use setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
If you're wondering how to apply to a widget, for example, a button, you can use 
ui->button->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);

Answer (score 4):

You can call `raise()` on your widget to make it appear in front of all other child widgets of the parent it is in.  If I read your question correctly, this is the behavior you want.  However, any child you create and add to a parent widget will automatically be placed above that widget, so you may need to reraise the widget after additions, or you may want to consider an alternate way of managing the parent/child relationship.