# How to make undocked QDockWidget stay visible when switching programs?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a few qdockwidgets in one qmainwindow. When I undock a window and I switch to another program the undocked widget disappears. How can I make the undocked QDockWidget visible or stay visible when I switch programs?

So, I've found out that the following line

```
super(MainProgram, self).__init__(parent,Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Makes sure that the whole program stays on top. However the undocked widget still disappears. Even when I put the following line in the qdockwidget code:

```
self.Risk_Monitor.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Surely it's possible to have floating widgets stay on top as well right?

The following doesn't seem to work as well:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dockdemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dockdemo, self).__init__(parent,Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")
        self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())


        items      = QDockWidget("Stay on Top!", self, flags=Qt.Window) 
        #items      = QDockWidget("Dockable", self, flags=Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)  # flags=Qt.Window
#        items.setGeometry(650, 130, 300, 200)
        items.show()                                                 # +++

        listWidget = QListWidget()
        listWidget.addItem("item1")
        listWidget.addItem("item2")
        listWidget.addItem("item3")
        items.setWidget(listWidget)
        items.setFloating(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dockdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*[Keep widget on top in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463125/keep-widget-on-top-in-qt)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Dockdemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dockdemo, self).__init__(parent,Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")
        self.setCentralWidget(QTextEdit())

        items      = QDockWidget("Dockable", self)  # flags=Qt.Window
        #items.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) 
#        items.setGeometry(650, 130, 300, 200)
        items.setWindowFlags(
        Qt.Window |
        Qt.CustomizeWindowHint |
        Qt.WindowTitleHint |
        Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint |
        Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        )
        items.show()                                              
        # items.raise_()
        listWidget = QListWidget()
        listWidget.addItem("item1")
        listWidget.addItem("item2")
        listWidget.addItem("item3")
        items.setWidget(listWidget)
        items.setFloating(False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Dockdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note that this does only work on Windows, it is not portable to other OS.

Comment: @Jens That is not true; I am on OSX and it works.